# Order of evaluation of expression in the update-set-clause in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

In a table I have column A and B. I want to update A using the value of B and then update B to a new value. This has to be done atomically.

I am trying something like this

```
-- Intially A = 1, B = 2
UPDATE T SET A = B, B = 10 WHERE ID = 1;
-- Now A = 2, B = 10
```

Though this is working, I am unable to find documentation which guarantees me that A = B is evaluated first and B = 10 is evaluated later.

I looked through the [oracle sql reference of the update statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this in SQL standard, which defines general rules.

Oracle certainly conforms to this standard.
See here - SQL 92:
http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Page 393, chapter "13.9 <update statement: positioned>", point 6)

> 6) **The <value expression>s are effectively evaluated before updat-
>               ing the object row.** If a  contains a reference
>               to a column of T, then the reference is to the value of that
>               column in the object row before any value of the object row is
>               updated.

Consider a general update syntax:<

```
UPDATE .... 
   SET <object column 1> = <value expression 1>,
       <object column 2> = <value expression 2>,
       ......
       <object column N> = <value expression N>;
```

The rule #6 says that all expressions on right side are evaluated first, before updating of any column in the row. 
Only old row's values (before the update) are considered while evaluating all expressions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is correct, although I would like to see a reference in the Oracle documentation about this (even one stating that it implements the ANSI semantics on `update`).

Comment: In this paper: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_standard_sql003.htm#SQLRF55516 Oracle guarantees, that their RDBMS provides full conformance of `E121-06, Positioned UPDATE statement` with SQL 2008 standard.

Answer (score 2):

In a RDBMS (unlike a programming language) there's no order of evaluation, it's all done at once. It's like you set variables to the previous value first and then use those variables:

```
SET a=b, b=a
```

simply switches `a` and `b`.

Warning: Only MySQL does it totally wrong, resulting in both set to the same `b` value, here you'll need a temp variable like:

```
SET temp=b, b=a, a = temp
```

Comment: It's not done "at once". First the right hand side is evaluated, and then the actual change is done (which indeed can be seen as "all at once")

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Oracle like any other RDBMS at first pool your data in a cache from your table then read from that cached info, So I think when you use a field name in the left side of a `SET`, the RDMBS read the value of your old data (before any change).

Comment: Oracle (and most other DBMS) will not lock the *table* for a single row update.

Answer (score 0):

SQL standard does not guarantee any order in the update statement.
I would suggest to run two updates in the desired order to make sure they are in the correct order.

```
-- Intially A = 1, B = 2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE T SET A = B WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE T SET B = 10 WHERE ID = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
-- Now A = 2, B = 10
```

Comment: That's not true. The SQL standard is pretty clear on how the left hand side and the right hand side are evaluated